# How to update manually Worklight from 6.1.0.0 to 6.1.0.1 (corrupted IIM install)

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server

I have some server with corrupted WL 6.1.0.0 install - the IIM does not show it in history, so I can not apply a fixpack in traditional way.

I need to update WL 6.1.0.0 to 6.1.0.1, in some non-traditional way.

Initially I thought that FixPack 001 major task is to update in **/opt/IBM/Worklight/WorklightServer/** files **worklight-ant-builder.jar, worklight-ant-deployer.jar, worklight-jee-library.jar** (besides WAR application update, which I don't need - we don't use App Center Console, and WL applications are built with Studio 6.1.0.1 - no need to update)

I planned to copy the JAR files from the updated server, but comparing with another server which was updated (via IIM) to 6.1.0.1 I see that these files are just the same (however About menu tells 6.1.0.1 server version).

App Center Console is not used on the 6.1.0.0 server (actually I uninstalled it via WAS web admin console)

So, my question is: how to update WL 6.1.0.0 to 6.1.0.1 manually, possibly in non-supported way?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with a manual way, however you should probably read and execute the recommended steps that are written in this user documentation topic: [Upgrading from Worklight Server V6.1.0 to V6.1.0.1 in a production environment](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.upgrade.doc/devenv/c_upgrade_to_srvr6101_fix_pack.html).

Highly suggested to also take a look [at the parent topic](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.upgrade.doc/devenv/c_upgrade_to_srvr610_in_production_env.html).

Comment: For sure I read all topics from InfoCenter, but from that link all tasks which not relate to any **modification** (because most of tasks just start/stop servers/applications) is to run Ant task 'minimal-update', but I believe it's more installed WAR update related. It's assumed that Worklight libraries were already updated via IIM to FixPack 001, and it makes WARs compliant to new minor revision.

Comment: The fix is in the studio plugin. Update and check again.

Comment: I am not sure I follow you. We do use in WL Studio 6.1.0.1, but server still remains at 6.1.0.0. How can WL studio plugin update the WL server?

Comment: Yes, I think a commented in the wrong question. :-) Why not try the upgrading again using a backup, using the steps above?